# Why aren't the lines without digits being printed?

Tags: java, graphics, scale, string-matching, args

Okay, in my class we're working on a project where we have to double every number in a program. We're doing this in order to scale an animation that we made for class. Here's my class scaling class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class DoubleEmRight
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(file);
        FileWriter input = new FileWriter("HolidayGraphics2.java");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(input);
        String s;
        do
        {
            int xn = 0;
            int countnum = 0;
            int xl = 0;
            int countlet = 0;
            boolean hasNum = false;
            boolean mult = false;
            s = kb.nextLine();
            String[]spLet = s.split("\\D"); //array w/ nums
            String[]spNum = s.split("\\d"); //array w/ letters
            String[]blklst = {"try", "for", "Color", "if", "waves.addPoint(x"};
            for (int i = 0; i < spLet.length; i++)
            {
                if (spLet[i].length() >=1)
                {
                    countnum++;
                }
            }
            String[]spLetNoSpc = new String[countnum];
            for (int i = 0; i < spLet.length; i++)
            {
                if (spLet[i].length() >=1)
                {
                    spLetNoSpc[xn] = spLet[i];
                    xn++;
                }
            } 

            for (int i = 0; i < spNum.length; i++)
            {
                if (spNum[i].length() >=1)
                {
                    countlet++;
                }
            }
            String[]spNumNoSpc = new String[countlet];
            for (int i = 0; i < spNum.length; i++)
            {
                if (spNum[i].length() >=1)
                {
                    spNumNoSpc[xl] = spNum[i];
                }
            } 
            search:
            for (int x = 0; x < spLetNoSpc.length ; x++)
            {

                find:
                for (int j = 0; j < blklst.length; j++)
                {
                    if (s.contains(blklst[j]))
                    {
                        mult = true;
                        break find;
                    }
                }
                if (!(s.matches(".*[0-9].*")))
                {
                    output.print(s);
                    break search;
                }
                else if (s.length() == 0)
                {
                    output.print(s);
                    break search;
                }
                else if (s.matches("for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++)"))
                {
                    output.print(spNumNoSpc[x] + (Integer.parseInt(spLetNoSpc[x])) * Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
                    if ((x == spLetNoSpc.length - 1)&&(spNumNoSpc.length > spLetNoSpc.length))
                    {
                        output.println(spNumNoSpc[x+1]);
                    }
                    break search;
                }   
                else if (mult)
                {
                    output.print(s);
                    break search;
                }
                else
                {
                    output.print(spNumNoSpc[x] + (Integer.parseInt(spLetNoSpc[x])) * Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
                    if ((x == spLetNoSpc.length - 1)&&(spNumNoSpc.length > spLetNoSpc.length))
                    {
                        output.println(spNumNoSpc[x+1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            output.println();
        }while(kb.hasNextLine());
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

This doubles all of the numbers in my animation's java file and prints it in a new file, HolidayGraphics2.java. Unfortunately, it doesn't print lines like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

But prints lines like this:

```
win.setSize(500,650);
```

Nor does it print any of my brackets.
These lines are supposed to print the original line from my animation program if the line does not contain a digit:

```
if (!(s.matches(".*[0-9].*")))
{
    output.print(s);
    break search;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the lines that don't contain digits are not printing? Here's the code for animation, just in case you need it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
//import java.awt.Graphics2D;
public class HolidayGraphics
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame win;
        Container contentPane;
        Graphics g;
        Panel controlPanel;

        win = new JFrame("Holiday Graphics");
        win.setSize(500,650);
        win.setLocation(100,100);
        win.setVisible(true);

        contentPane = win.getContentPane();   // activates graphics in window
        g = contentPane.getGraphics();
        try {Thread.sleep(400);} catch (Exception e) {}

       for(int w = 0; w < 10000; w++)
       {
        g.setColor(new Color(231,252,252)); //sky
        g.fillRect(0,0,500,650);

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW); //sun
        g.fillOval(20,20,80,80);
        g.drawLine(60,110,60,145);
        g.drawLine(40,90,5,125);
        g.drawLine(80,90,115,125);
        g.drawLine(80,30,115,0);
        g.drawLine(110,60,145,60);

        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255)); //ice
        g.fillRect(300,170,200,50);

        Polygon waves = new Polygon(); //waves
        for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++)
        {
            waves.addPoint(x, 180 + (int)Math.sin(x*((Math.PI)/2))*3);
        }
        waves.addPoint(500, 650);
        waves.addPoint(0, 650);
        g.setColor(new Color(67,129,243));
        g.fillPolygon(waves);

        g.setColor(new Color(67,129,243)); //water
        g.fillRect(0,190,500,700);

        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255)); //ice over water
        g.fillRect(300,170,200,30);

        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i = i+2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    
            g.fillRect(340,174 - i*6,10,6); 
        } 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,168,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,156,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,144,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,132,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,120,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,108,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,96,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,84,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,72,10,6); 
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
        g.fillRect(340,60,10,6); 

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);          //sign
        g.fillOval(305,24,80,30);
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        g.drawOval(305,24,80,30);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("North Pole",313,43);

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);        //penguin       
        g.fillOval(400,178,20,10);
        g.fillOval(425,178,20,10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);          
        g.fillOval(388,82,70,100);
        g.fillOval(385,132,15,30);
        g.fillOval(446,132,15,30);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(400,102,25,25);
        g.fillOval(421,102,25,25);
        g.fillOval(398,123,50,55);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(410,110,6,6);//eye
        g.fillOval(430,110,6,6);//eye
        g.drawLine(406,110,415,105);//eyebrow
        g.drawLine(439,110,430,105);//eyebrow
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);          
        g.fillOval(400,178,20,10);
        g.fillOval(425,178,20,10);
        Polygon nose = new Polygon();
        nose.addPoint(415,118);
        nose.addPoint(431,118);
        nose.addPoint(423,126);
        g.fillPolygon(nose);

        g.setColor(new Color(255,122,119)); //house
        g.fillRect(150,450,200,100); 
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Santa's Workshop", 190, 470);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i=i+2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);    
            g.fillRect(150,480 + 10*i,10,10); 
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i=i+2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    
            g.fillRect(150,480 + 10*i,10,10); 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i=i+2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);    
            g.fillRect(340,480 + 10*i,10,10); 
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i=i+2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    
            g.fillRect(340,480 + 10*i,10,10); 
        }

        g.setColor(new Color(124,29,5)); //chimney
        g.fillRect(170,400,10,50);

        g.setColor(new Color(130,62,0)); //roof
        Polygon tri1 = new Polygon();
        tri1.addPoint(150,450);
        tri1.addPoint(250,390);
        tri1.addPoint(350,450);
        g.fillPolygon(tri1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 390; i++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);          
            g.fillOval(70+i,350,40,20);         //fish 1
            Polygon fishtri1 = new Polygon();
            fishtri1.addPoint(70+i,350);
            fishtri1.addPoint(70+i,370);
            fishtri1.addPoint(87+i,360);
            g.fillPolygon(fishtri1);

            g.fillOval(70+i,220,40,20);         //fish 2
            Polygon fishtri2 = new Polygon();
            fishtri2.addPoint(70+i,220);
            fishtri2.addPoint(70+i,240);
            fishtri2.addPoint(87+i,230);
            g.fillPolygon(fishtri2);

            g.fillOval(430 - i,285,40,20);      //fish 3
            Polygon fishtri3 = new Polygon();
            fishtri3.addPoint(470-i,285);
            fishtri3.addPoint(470-i,305);
            fishtri3.addPoint(453-i,295);
            g.fillPolygon(fishtri3);

            try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (Exception e) {}

            if (!(i==389))
            {
                g.setColor(new Color(67,129,243));
                g.fillOval(70+i,350,40,20);
                g.fillPolygon(fishtri1);
                g.fillOval(70+i,220,40,20); 
                g.fillPolygon(fishtri2);
                g.fillOval(430 - i,285,40,20);  
                g.fillPolygon(fishtri3);
            } 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) //bubbles
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawOval(167 - i*15, 380-i*30, 10 + i*i, 10 + i*i);
            try {Thread.sleep(200*i);} catch (Exception e) {}
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to double EVERY number? what about color values?

Comment: @samgak no i don't, that's why I made a blacklist for numbers i don't want to double. So, any line that has the word color, if, try, or for won't have doubled numbers